# Error when importing variables from another file

Tags: python, csv, variables, import, module

I am importing 'testmod' file onto my 'main' file and encountered the following error:

```
NameError: name 'apple' is not defined
```

How to I ensure that the all variables on 'testmod' file such as 'year', 'banana', 'apple' are readable on the 'main' file

The following files:

sampledata.csv:

```
Year,Apple,Orange,,,
2011,45,67,,,
2012,48,43,,,
2013,58,89,,,
```

'testmod' file:

```
import csv

def insertcsv():
    openfile = open('sampledata.csv')
    csvreader = csv.reader(openfile)
    next(csvreader)
    
    year=[]
    apple=[]
    orange=[]

    for row in csvreader:
        year.append(row)
        apple.append(row)
        orange.append(row)
    
    return year
    return apple
    return orange

def calfruits:
    cal = [apple[i] + orange[i] for i in range(len(apple))]
```

Importing the 'testmod' on 'main':

```
import testmod as tmod
tmod.insertcsv()
print(apple)
print(cal)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out.

**'testmod' file:**

```
import csv
def insertcsv():
    openfile = open('sampledata.csv')
    csvreader = csv.reader(openfile)
    next(csvreader)
    
    year=[]
    apple=[]
    orange=[]

    for row in csvreader:
        year.append(row)
        apple.append(row)
        orange.append(row)
    
    return year,apple,orange # return all values in a single line.

def calfruits():
    cal = [apple[i] + orange[i] for i in range(len(apple))]
    return cal
```

**Importing the 'testmod' on 'main':**

```
import testmod as tmod
year,apple,orange = tmod.insertcsv()
cal = tmod.calfruits()
print(apple)
print(cal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the insertcsv() return a local variable called apple but you need to provide a global variable to use in the print statement. Since we are here, there you are some suggestions:
Instead of three separate return statement use this

```
    return year, apple, orange
```

Than retrieve the values by saying

```
    year, apple, orange = tmod.insertcsv()
```

This would do it

Answer (score 0):

Return all values in a line because once it return a value then your function will be terminated .

use :
return year, apple, orange
Insted of:
return year
return apple
return orange